# Where does mysql save the path for gearman mysql udf files?

Tags: mysql, shared-libraries, user-defined-functions, gearman

I have been trying to use gearman mysql udf. I have downloaded tarball from http://gearman.org/index.php?id=download and installed it with the instructions given on http://gearman.org/index.php?id=mysql_udf_readme
I am trying to create the gman_do function in mysql, but I am getting some error
The Error is-

```
mysql> create function gman_do returns string soname "libgearman_mysql_udf.so";
ERROR 1126 (HY000): Can't open shared library 'libgearman_mysql_udf.so' (errno: 22 /usr/local/lib/libgearman_mysql_udf.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I must have changed some variable path for the shared library. `MySQL` should find the `libgearman_mysql_udf.so` from the `plugindir` which is `/usr/lib/mysql/plugin` which was given by me at the time of the installation using -

```
bash configure --with-mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config --libdir=/usr/lib/mysql/plugin
make
make install
```

What should I do? Where how should I make `MySQL` look for the `.so` files of the `gearman_mysql_udf` to some other directory, say the `plugindir`.

Comment: From your read-me link, "Please keep in mind that for your UDF to be loaded, it must be in
the library path for your server. On most UNIX-like systems you can
set this by exporting the correct path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH for your
mysql server." What about LD_LIBRARY_PATH. Have you set that path properly

Comment: My `my.cnf` file is in /etc/mysql. So I guess that is the path of my `mysql` server. So should I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to /etc/mysql ? Also note that my libgearman_mysq_udf.so* files are in /usr/lib/mysql/plugin and my LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not set yet.