# how to configure gearmand with libdrizzle on linux?

Tags: jobs, gearman, libdrizzle

I have been trying to work with persistent job queues of gearman. When I try to use libdrizzle like-

```
gearmand -q libdrizzle --libdrizzle-host=127.0.0.1 --libdrizzle-user=gearman --libdrizzle-password=secret --libdrizzle-db=some_db --libdrizzle-table=gearman_queue --libdrizzle-mysql
```

It gives me error like-

```
gearmand: unknown option libdrizzle-host
```

Also a strange thing is that when I do `man gearmand` it does not have the libdrizzle options. What should I do? I want the persistent queues in mysql. I had tried using `gearman_udf_mysql` but it did not work too. I have posted the problem. see [Where does mysql save the path for gearman mysql udf files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12476391/where-does-mysql-save-the-path-for-gearman-mysql-udf-files)

Answer (score 0):

Gearman must be compiled with libdrizzle/mysql support.  You can check if it's been compiled in by running the command `gearmand --help` or on older versions `man gearmand`.

If libdrizzle/mysql support is available, you will see the Drizzle/Mysql options in the help.  If it's not there, you will need to recompile gearmand.  Here are the commands to install Gearman 1.1.12 on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (tested on a clean Vagrant precise64 box):

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get update
vagrant@precise64:~$ sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev gperf libevent-dev uuid-dev libmysqld-dev
vagrant@precise64:~$ wget https://launchpad.net/gearmand/1.2/1.1.12/+download/gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
vagrant@precise64:~$ tar zxvf gearmand-1.1.12.tar.gz
vagrant@precise64:~$ cd gearmand-1.1.12/
vagrant@precise64:~/gearmand-1.1.12$ ./configure
```

At this point, look for the following lines at the end of the `./configure` output, which indicates Mysql support is installed:

```
* Building with libdrizzle   yes
* Building with libmysql     yes
```

Then continue with the installation:

```
vagrant@precise64:~/gearmand-1.1.12$ make
vagrant@precise64:~/gearmand-1.1.12$ sudo make install
```

Gearmand is now configured with libdrizzle and will store jobs in a Mysql database.